# Output a floating point value with a constant number of characters in C++

Tags: c++, formatting, floating-point

I'm having trouble doing what I think should be a fairly simple task in C++. I'm trying to output a floating point value to be written into a log file. The log file has 7 characters designated for the number output, but I'm finding it to be a little nontrivial to get a constant 7 character output over a wide range of values of different magnitudes, signs, and precisions (eg: 1, -0.60937, 0.60937, 0.009371, -0.009371). I've got a somewhat hacked way to kinda do it:

```
int desiredPrecision = 6;
if (runningAvg < 0)
  desiredPrecision--;
if (std::abs((long) runningAvg) < 1)
  desiredPrecision--;
else
  theFile << std::showpoint;

theFile.precision (desiredPrecision);

theFile.fill('0');
theFile.setf(std::ios_base::left, std::ios_base::adjustfield);
theFile.width(7);
theFile << runningAvg << std::endl;
```

But this way seems extremely hacky to me. It works with numbers like:
-0.60937 (outputs: -0.6094)

-1.7 (-1.7000)

-1 (-1.0000)

0.6937 (0.60937)

0.00937 (0.00937)

but it breaks with
0.009371 (0.009371)

and

-0.009371 (-0.009371)

Now, I could add another level of if-else statements to deal with small magnitude numbers, but that just seems to be adding to the level of hackiness, and not a clean way to do it. I've played a bit with fprintf, but it seems like it is more concerned with a strict mathematical definition of precision, whereas in this application I care more about restricting the width of the field to 7 characters at all times. (I can also rely on these numbers never being so large that I'll overflow 6 characters plus a sign)

Am I missing something obvious here? Anyone have any tips for a less hacked way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you expect the output of -99999 to be?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how to do this with `iostream` stuff but I think that the `?printf` format string you're looking for is one of these:

- `%.4f` for negative numbers and `%07.5f` for positive numbers.
- `%+.4f` (positive numbers will have a leading `+`)
- `% .4f` (positive numbers will have a leading space)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to print into a string and chop the string.
You are really doing text processing/report generation not floating point number handling sop treat it as a formatting problem

Comment: Proper rounding is definitely not a string-manipulation task.

Comment: +1, although i agree with @BenVoigt, given that this is going into a log file, this is a possibility and doesn't deserve a -1.

Comment: I played around with this, and it seems like this is probably the easiest way to go. I set up a simple do-while loop to output to a c++ std::string, and chop the precision by 1 if the string length is over 7 (with a max # of times through the loop to take care of overflow).

@BenVoigt - I agree in theory, but as I said, I'm looking to write to a log file that has a requirement of fixed width for the number, in this application I'm not concerned with mathematically rigorous (read correct sigfigs) rounding/precision.
Thanks!

Comment: @bencpeters - proper rounding isn't, but formatting a number to fit into 20characters is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concern with precision (or concern enough to use the same precision for all numbers) you could use the same `"%7.0e"` format for all numbers.

[Example](http://ideone.com/9MQ8z)

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char* format = "%7.0e";

int main() {
  double a[] = {1, -0.60937, 0.60937, 0.009371, -0.009371,
               -1, -1.2e8, 1e-4, 1e-5, -1.5e-321, 0/.0, 1/0.};
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a); ++i) {
    printf(format, a[i]);
    puts("");
    if (snprintf(0,0, format, a[i]) != 7)
      return 1;
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
  1e+00
 -6e-01
  6e-01
  9e-03
 -9e-03
 -1e+00
 -1e+08
  1e-04
  1e-05
-2e-321
    nan
    inf
```